# css properties apply only by code - javascript

Tags: javascript, css

In my firefox extension I created a `div` element and added to it a paragraph with id named `myP`.

In the css file I wrote:

```
#myP
{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 7px 7px; 
}
```

but only the first two properties applied to the paragraph.

I tried to set the three others properties in my js code:

```
myP.style.fontSize = "16px";
myP.style.fontWeight = "900";
myP.style.margin = "7px 7px";
```

and it worked perfectly.

how can it be?

Comment: It worked for me, though having said that `p` elements aren't supposed to contain block elements like `div`s. Can you demonstrate the problem with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Manatok already solved it, thanks anyway. I think I did not understand you well, the `p` element is inside the `div` not the opposite

Comment: My apologies, I misread your question vis-a-vis which element was being added to which. I guess Manatok's answer also explains why it worked for me: I didn't have any other styles set that could clash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is something else that is overriding your styles, can you inspect it in any way?

Have you tried:

```
#myP
{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 900 !important;
    margin: 7px 7px !important; 
}
```

Comment: you are right. it is working now, thanks! is it because maybe in the page's css file there is these properties to all `p` elements?